# How can I have the matrix file with the calculated distance values from "Distance widget" in Orange?

Tags: widget, report, distance, orange

We want to get the complete matrix with the calculated distance values from the Orange GUI. We tried selecting the data from a `Data Table` widget linked to a `Distance Map` widget that has selected the complete matrix. But instead to have the distance matrix we obtain the original data.

We also try to generate a report from the `Distance` widget but it only shows the parameter values, not the matrix.

Any ideas to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

Distance Map outputs signal of type Table, which contains the original data. This is what you got in the Table widget - Orange connected these signals automatically since the types matched. Table widget, however, shows only Tables, not Distance matrices. As far as I know, there is no way to see the actual numbers in tabular form. They are usually not too interesting since the matrices are typically too big to be displayed and analyzed in this way -- unless you're measuring correlations between attributes, but for these cases there are (or at least were, in Orange 2) widgets that show correlations and corresponding scatter plots.

I've put something together, though. If you use Orange 3, download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janezd/orange3/add-distance-matrix/Orange/widgets/unsupervised/owdistancematrix.py
and put it into directory Orange/widgets/unsupervised.

If you want to discuss it further, you'd better write [a github issue](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues).